# How do I prevent my photos from automatically syncing from my iPhone to my Mac?

Tags: imac, iphone

I need help. so the photos from my iPhone 5S, when connected to the iMac, will automatically sync and the photos from my iPhone 5S can be seen on the iPhoto on iMac. how do I stop this ? I don't want anyone to check my photos when using yhe iMac. I want privacy.  I want to set a lock on the iPhone to prevent the pictures from being synced and connected to iPhoto.

Comment: if you turn off syncing as shown in the below answer your phone will no longer sync. if you want to protect the photos in your iphoto library that are already there I would suggest exporting them to a new photo library then put that library on a password protected disk image and mount and dismount as needed. Remove the images from the main library

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't prevent your iPhone from doing things on the user end of tasks. Thats the user's job. Secondly if your concern is privacy, automatic sync to iPhoto is the lesser of your worries. iCloud automatically syncs your photos to the cloud which can be seen from any device using your apple ID. If your computer is a publicly used computer a specific password protected login account would be a better fit for you.

Regardless, to answer your question is a quick and easy method. Go to your spotlight search and type Image Capture or you can find the application in your 'Applications' folder.

When the device is plugged in you will see its title populate in the left sidebar. Click on it. This is what your screen will now show:
[image: Device Screenshot]

You may or may not see the bottom bar, if not just expand it to show more options and your screen will now look like this:
[image: Change Settings Screenshot]

Simply change your method to No Applications. Alternatively, this can be done within iPhoto preferences, however, I just wanted to point this option out to you for future references.

Comment: I can't set a lock on my iPhone to prevent other iMac users to see it? cause it works If I restart my iPhone and the photos will not appear in the iPhoto in my iMac

Comment: @Rider You can set a lock to your iPhone anytime, but that doesn't stop the photos from syncing. The process I outlined can.

Comment: so there's no way I can't stop my older sister from checking my photos ?